# passing kickstart file using virtualbox headless(VBoxManage) linux

Tags: virtualbox, headless

I am trying to install centos as virtual machine using virtualbox headless(VBoxManage). I am able to create the virtual machine using VBoxManage.

How do I pass the kickstart file using VBoxManage to make the installation automated.

This is my **script file** to create vm.

```
VM="test"
VBoxManage createhd --filename $VM.vdi --size 32768
VBoxManage createvm --name $VM --ostype "RedHat_64" --register
VBoxManage storagectl $VM --name "SATA Controller" --add sata  --controller IntelAHCI
VBoxManage storageattach $VM --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium $VM.vdi
VBoxManage storagectl $VM --name "IDE Controller" --add ide
VBoxManage storageattach $VM --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium /path/to/iso
VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --ioapic on
VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --boot1 dvd --boot2 disk --boot3 none --boot4 none
VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --memory 1024 --vram 128
VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0
```

How do I make changes in my script to pass kickstart file

Answer (score 0):

You may find a clever solution based on a local http server in ruby in that code

https://github.com/astrostl/vagrant-centos/blob/master/vagrant-centos

```
ruby -rsocket -e 'puts "Kickstart URL: ks=http://" + Socket.ip_address_list.find { |ai| ai.ipv4? && !ai.ipv4_loopback? }.ip_address + ":8000/vagrant-centos-MAJORVERSION.ks"'
ruby -rwebrick -e 's=WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port=>8000,:DocumentRoot=>".");trap("INT") { s.shutdown }; s.start'
```